# Using Neo4j with Opa

Tags: database, neo4j, opa

How do I use Neo4j as database with Opa?

Does db support has to be added to Opa before I can use a particular db?

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j has a REST API with a JSON interface.
It would be easy to communicate with this db in Opa.

Search `WebClient` and `Json` in http://doc.opalang.org